# Single tap gesture to multiple View using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, uitapgesturerecognizer

How to have single tap gesture to multiple Views using storyboard.

I drag 3 views and one tap gesture into UIView class.
Contacted three view to tap gesture and added action class handleGesture Method on tap on any one the tree view it should trigger the method action.
using story board.

But i want to do it with single tap gesture is it possible or not.

Comment: no it is not possible. You have to add three different tap gestures to UIviews. and call the same method.

Comment: It's not possible there is only a `UIView` property availble on `UITapGestureRecognizer` class.

Comment: What exactly is your requirement

Comment: @JafferSheriff single gesture with multiple view can share it.

Comment: U can't add multiple gestures with same selectors

Answer (score 0):

try with this, define a variable UITapGestureRecognizer with your method, after that, in a method or wherever you want, you can add this gesture to your multiple views

```
var recognizerMovements: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    get { UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.myActionMethod)) }
}

self.myFirstView.addGestureRecognizer(myActionMethod)
self.mySecondView.addGestureRecognizer(myActionMethod)
```